# insmod of a loadable kernel mdoule is causing exception with signal 4

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I was using linux 3.14 where we had many kernel modules loaded and working fine.
I applied some official patches fixing some vulnerabilities, to my existing kernel, after that the previous loadable module is failing to load.

I am getting kernel exception and going to KGDB, without any error message on the console.

### logs:

bash# /sbin/insmod -f [module file]

[ 1028.720605] KGDB: Waiting for remote debugger

### STACK DUMP

```
[  158.670810]  [<ffffffffb8c6e7ed>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
[  158.732379]  [<ffffffffb88ae189>] kgdb_handle_exception+0x3f/0x4d
[  158.805404]  [<ffffffffb882c164>] __kgdb_notify+0xda/0xeb
[  158.870089]  [<ffffffffb882c198>] kgdb_notify+0x23/0x44
[  158.932695]  [<ffffffffb8c76073>] notifier_call_chain+0x39/0x5c
[  159.003632]  [<ffffffffb8c760b8>] atomic_notifier_call_chain+0x13/0x15
[  159.081862]  [<ffffffffb8c760f3>] notify_die+0x39/0x40
[  159.143426]  [<ffffffffb8802c14>] do_invalid_op+0x6e/0xdb
[  159.208114]  [<ffffffffb8808254>] ? apply_alternatives+0x7d/0x455
[  159.281136]  [<ffffffffb88ed937>] ? zone_statistics+0x71/0x78
[  159.349991]  [<ffffffffb8a25f97>] ? trace_hardirqs_off_thunk+0x3a/0x6c
[  159.428221]  [<ffffffffb8c73130>] ? irq_return+0xa/0xa
[  159.489781]  [<ffffffffb8c7af65>] invalid_op+0x15/0x20
[  159.551345]  [<ffffffffb8808254>] ? apply_alternatives+0x7d/0x455
[  159.624371]  [<ffffffffb889340d>] ? each_symbol_section.part.10+0x17e/0x1ba
[  159.707811]  [<ffffffffb8892243>] ? cmp_name+0xd/0xf
[  159.767290]  [<ffffffffb8a2941a>] ? bsearch+0x4b/0x7b
[  159.827812]  [<ffffffffb8892236>] ? unregister_module_notifier+0x15/0x15
[  159.908124]  [<ffffffffb889239b>] ? find_symbol_in_section+0x36/0xdc
[  159.984270]  [<ffffffffb8892365>] ? mod_find_symname+0x60/0x60
[  160.054167]  [<ffffffffb889346a>] ? each_symbol_section+0x21/0x44
[  160.127188]  [<ffffffffb8a263fc>] ? sort+0x113/0x1aa
[  160.186669]  [<ffffffffb882b860>] module_finalize+0xb8/0xf9
[  160.253441]  [<ffffffffb8894e55>] load_module+0x1335/0x1ca2
[  160.320212]  [<ffffffffb8892c6a>] ? copy_module_from_fd+0x9c/0xfc
[  160.393237]  [<ffffffffb88b5269>] ? rb_commit+0x7e/0x85
[  160.455847]  [<ffffffffb88958b8>] SyS_finit_module+0x59/0x66
[  160.523664]  [<ffffffffb88958b8>] ? SyS_finit_module+0x59/0x66
[  160.593562]  [<ffffffffb8c7b6c8>] ia32_do_call+0x1f/0x1f
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `load_module` plus immediate `module_finalize` suggests that the module's initialization function have return an error. But without viewing the code we can only guess... [That means, you need to add your code into the question for make it *answerable*. It is a rule of Stack Overflow.]

Answer (score 0):

Issue was because there was new fields added in some data structure, and those .h files were not used to rebuild the old klm's.

Rebuilding the KLM's with new .h files fixed the issue.